# Adding Swift Class to Objective-C Project with Multiple Targets

Tags: objective-c, swift3, bridging-header

I have an existing Obj-C project that houses many targets that all share the same AppDelegate. I want to bridge a swift class that is used by select targets. I can do this easily when I have one target.

When I add a swift file to the project, I select the desired targets and the necessary bridging-header.h files are generated, but when I try to import those -swift.h files, they are can't be found.

Are there steps I'm missing when it comes to projects that have multiple build targets?

**EDIT - More Details**

I wanted to add a little bit more detail on how my project is set up.

[image]

I have a Framework, we'll call it AppFactory, coded in Obj-C. I have multiple build targets that generate different versions of the Core app depending on information in that target's plist. I want a swift file to be utilized by these apps. In my build settings the Defines Module is marked to Yes, I have create this swift class:

```
@objec class SwiftClass: NSObject { }
```

And in doing that, Xcode generated the proper Briding-Header.h files.

According to [Apple Guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID130) when you have multiple build targets your import header should include the ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h, which should be auto generated by Xcode.

When I look in to my derived data folder, the ProductModuleName-Swift.h does exist, with in each targets build folder, under the AppFactoryCore folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

**Swift File Targets:**
Instead of having SwiftClass.swift target both the framework and the selected targets (AppA, AppB & AppC), I backpedaled and solely targeted the framework, AppFactoryCore.

**Build Settings (Packaging > Defines Module):**
I reverted each app target's `Defines Module` property from `YES` to `NO`, and set this property to `YES` for the framework target.

**Swift Class Declaration:**
The [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID130) states:

> Because the generated header for a framework target is part of the framework’s public interface, only declarations marked with the public or open modifier appear in the generated header for a framework target.

So I added access control modifiers to my class and class functions

```
@objc open class SwiftClass: NSObject {
    //Code
}
```

**Import Header**:
Since SwiftClass.swift is only targeting the framework target, and it is in fact a framework that is being used, the header import SwiftClass.swift into the universal AppDelegate was

```
#import <AppFactoryCore/AppFactoryCore-Swift.h>
```

Which finally became visible once all previously stated modifications were done.

Now that the file is global to all targets I added a custom attribute to identify if the target running was is one that should utilize SwiftClass.swift.

Hope this helps anyone else trying to accomplish a relatively similar task!