# Stuck in Importing and Using Swift ViewController to Objective C class.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am stuck at a weird situation.I have a **ViewController** written in **Swift**.It is basically an intro screen ViewController.

Now I want to use it in **Obj-C Code**.But I am unable with an error of "Use of undeclared indentifier" when ever i try to create its object.

*Following are the check points i have already followed:*

- **import "homer_iOS-Swift.h"** in my ViewController where homer_iOS is mine project(homer_iOS is mine target/Project name).

  target Name.
- Cross checked the **BuildSetting > Define Module** to **Yes** for both Target and Project.
- Cross check the **BuildSetting > Objective C generated Interface Header >

     homer_iOS-Swift.h**
- **@objc** before mine Swift ViewController class.

Please dont just mark it as duplicate and move on as suggestions on same types questions are already tried out.
 Any Help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: But IntroSwipeVC is a swift file.which is already added as IntroSwipeVC.swift

Comment: where did you add IntroSwipeVc ?

Comment: IntroSwipeVC.swift and IntroSwipeVC.xib were added in a group named Utils. IntroSwipeVC.swift started appearing in Build Phase > Compile Sources with file path

Comment: Xcode 8.3.x might be an improvement over this, but I've noticed that 8.2.x still *shows* these kinds of errors in Objective-C code (inability to find Swift symbols), but the project actually *builds* successfully.  Have you tried to actually build your project to see if it's maybe just a UI glitch?

Comment: this is more likely to same issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599970/adding-swift-class-to-objective-c-project-with-multiple-targets/43600881#43600881

Comment: @fullofsquirrels i am using xcode 8.3.2 and i tried to build but it failed.

Comment: @liangju issue is somewhat same but nothing from answer worked for me.

Comment: What do you see when you Command+Click on `IntroSwipeVC` in that line of code?